# Android - Layout type for ordering app

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating my first app in Android, but I'm confused which layout type I should have for one of my activities.  I want a list of restaurant menu items displayed so I was thinking LinearLayout.  However, each of these items should have name, description, price, quantity.  As a result, I'm now thinking of a LinearLayout with Fragments where each menu item is a fragment.  Note that the menu items are dynamic retrieved from a server.  Is this a suitable approach for the UI layout or should I be using something else?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use a ListView... and i dont think it depends on the layout it self. If the important thing is you want to add data dynamically from database, a ListView should work and it has nothing to do with the layout(except for designing your UI)

Comment: Just for your information, if you are very new to android www.thenewboston.com should help a lot(and its video tuts free) :D